# Как выделить память для большого двумерного массива в Си?

Tags: c, массивы, память

Я работаю с большим двумерным массивом.

В случае, когда он размером 30 x 200, все считается. При больших объемах программа вылетает... Мне посоветовали использовать memset(), но что-то не особо помогает...
Может быть у вас есть какие идеи?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

double **B;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int N, n_A;

    N = 32;
    n_A = 350; /* если сделать n_A = 200, то все работает */
    B = (double **)malloc(N * sizeof(double *));

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        B[i] = (double *)malloc(n_A * sizeof(double));
        memset(B[i], 0, n_A * sizeof(double));
    }

    free(B);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну не знаю, скопировал, объявил i, скомпилял, работает... <br />Чем собираешь, когда сыпется что говорит?<br />Изменил n_A на 3500 тоже работает...

Comment: У меня тоже работает. Нужно поменять n_A на 1000000000, и оно упадет :)

Comment: Я могу только предположить. Попробуйте написать под x64)

Answer (score 4):

В целом код правильный, но нужно добавить проверку при выделении памяти: это необходимо, потому что памяти может просто не хватать, и в этом случае программа будет падать, потому что будет происходить запись в несуществующую память. То есть всякий раз, когда происходит вызов malloc, необходимо проверить, что возвращаемое значение не равно NULL.

```
B = (double **)malloc(N * sizeof(double *));

/* Проверить, что память выделена */
if (B != NULL)
{
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        B[i] = (double *)malloc(n_A * sizeof(double));

        /* Проверить, что память выделена */
        if (B[i] != NULL)
        {
            memset(B[i], 0, n_A * sizeof(double));
            free(B[i]);
        }
    }

    free(B);
}
```

Кроме того, нужно не забывать освобождать память, выделяемую malloc внутри цикла, иначе будут утечки.

Comment: Да, все верно, в коде из первого поста не освобождается вся память, при чем ее основная часть утекает =)

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает =))

Comment: Используйте electric fence?

Comment: Ммм,попробую. Хотя его стоит применять для небольших программ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот это все можно сделать одной строкой

```
double * B;
B = (double *) calloc (N * n_A, sizeof(double));
free (B);
```

Вместо вызова кучи функций вы вызываете одну, которая сразу выделяет память под весь массив данных и обнуляет ее.

Доступ к данным осуществляется по формуле

```
double a;
a = *(B + i * n_A + j);
```

где i - номер  строки, j - номер столбца

Answer (score 0):

> При больших объемах программа вылетает...

Локальный буфер(точнее размер стекового фрейма) не должен иметь размер больший одной страницы. Иначе произойдёт обращение за пределы сторожевой страницы стека, расширен он не будет и возникнет исключение.